# How can Stylus be configured to require colons and semicolons?

Tags: stylus

Is there a way to limit the amount of omissions that Stylus allows? Particularly in a team environment, force the use of the pythonic layout with colons and semicolons.

I cannot find any documentation on configuring compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's no way to force this behavior when compiling with Stylus.
It's syntax is almost identical as SASS, you should consider using it.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing code style is not a responsibility for Stylus. The situation with team environment to keep code style consistent is exactly why linting tools were created for and are commonly used for Javascript (ESLint, JSLint), CSS, SCSS etc.

For Stylus there is [**Stylint**](https://github.com/SimenB/stylint). Use it as a CLI tool, Git hook or in your Continous Integration service. There are also plugins with integrations for popular IDEs:

- [Atom](https://atom.io/packages/linter-stylint)
- [Sublime Text](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-contrib-stylint)
- [WebStorm / PhpStorm / IntelliJ IDEA](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9162)
- [Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vtfn.stylint)